# catch exception in job execution for telegram bot

Tags: python, exception, schedule, telethon

I am writing a method which will send message to the list of telegram user.
I am creating it as a job which will run every day at 8:30 in the morning and send "good morning message".

```
@catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=True)
async def send_message():

    message = 'Good Morning'
    
    list_of_user_to_send_message = bot_team_data() # method to fetch data from DB

    if type(list_of_user_to_send_message) is not list:
        return

    for telegramId in list_of_user_to_send_message:
        if type(telegramId) is not int:
            user = int(telegramId)
            logger.info('Good morning message sent to {user}'.format(user=telegramId))
            try:
                await bot.send_message(user, message)
            except ValueError as e:
                logger.exception(
                    'User with telegramId {id} is not interacted with the bot, {e}'.format(id=telegramId, e=e),
                    stack_info=True)
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                logger.exception(
                    'Error occurred for the telegramId {id} and the error is {e}'.format(id=telegramId, e=e),
                    stack_info=True)
                continue
```

I am using aioschedule package to run the method as a job.
I am also created a method to catch any unknown exception and cancel the job.
But it is not able to work.
Below code is how I implemented to catch exception.

```
import functools
import aioschedule as schedule
import asyncio


def catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False):
    def catch_exceptions_decorator(job_func):
        @functools.wraps(job_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return job_func(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                import traceback
                if cancel_on_failure:
                    return schedule.CancelJob

        return wrapper

    return catch_exceptions_decorator


def main():
    bot.start()
    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    bot.run_until_disconnected()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying this code to generate an error :

```
import configparser
import functools
import aioschedule as schedule
import asyncio

from telethon import TelegramClient

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
parser.read("../application.yml")

api_id = parser.get("telegram-config", "api_id")
api_hash = parser.get("telegram-config", "api_hash")
bot_token = parser.get("telegram-config", "bot_token")


bot = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)


def catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=False):
    print('try 1')

    def catch_exceptions_decorator(job_func):
        print('try 2')

        @functools.wraps(job_func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                print('try 3')
                return job_func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                print('exception')
                import traceback
                if cancel_on_failure:
                    return schedule.CancelJob

        return wrapper

    return catch_exceptions_decorator


@catch_exceptions(cancel_on_failure=True)
async def send_message():
    message = 'Good Morning'
    print('send message')
    await bot.send_message('1234', message)


def main():
    bot.start()

    schedule.every().day.at("10:00").do(send_message)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    bot.run_until_disconnected()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
try 1
try 2
try 3
send message
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-115736' coro=<Job.run() done, defined at D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py:455> exception=ValueError('Cannot get entity by phone number as a bot (try using integer IDs, not strings)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 501, in _get_entity_from_string
    for user in (await self(
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 77, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetContactsRequest)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 462, in run
    ret = await self.job_func()
  File "D:/Project/telegram_bot/src/try_exception_catch.py", line 64, in send_message
    await bot.send_message('1234', message)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 697, in send_message
    entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 413, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 506, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError('Cannot get entity by phone number as a '
ValueError: Cannot get entity by phone number as a bot (try using integer IDs, not strings)
try 3
send message
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-115738' coro=<Job.run() done, defined at D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py:455> exception=ValueError('Cannot get entity by phone number as a bot (try using integer IDs, not strings)')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 501, in _get_entity_from_string
    for user in (await self(
  File "D:\Project\telegram_botvenv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 77, in _call
    result = await future
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.BotMethodInvalidError: The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetContactsRequest)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aioschedule\__init__.py", line 462, in run
    ret = await self.job_func()
  File "D:/Project/telegram_bot/src/try_exception_catch.py", line 64, in send_message
    await bot.send_message('1234', message)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\messages.py", line 697, in send_message
    entity = await self.get_input_entity(entity)
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 413, in get_input_entity
    await self._get_entity_from_string(peer))
  File "D:\Project\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 506, in _get_entity_from_string
    raise ValueError('Cannot get entity by phone number as a '
ValueError: Cannot get entity by phone number as a bot (try using integer IDs, not strings)
```

Value Error is continuously coming in the terminal.

Comment: Is your `bot` connected? Do you `bot.start()` it somewhere?

Comment: yes, I am sorry I will edit it.

Comment: Are you sure the code is executed at all (e.g. by adding a `print` and seeing if it runs)?

Comment: Yes, code is executed but not able to go to the except part of the method wrapper in the catch_exceptions part.

Comment: Added the code which I am trying to generate error and added the output.

Comment: The problem is you're using a string with digits for to represent the user, which the library identifies as a phone number. You want to use an integer, like the error indicates (`1234` and not `'1234'`).

Comment: I am generating this error purposely, My problem is that the catch_exception annotation should catch the exception and stop the scheduler. But it is not able to stop the scheduler after the method send_message throws the error.

Comment: My problem is that if the method throws any kind of error which is not handled then the scheduler should stop.

Comment: Does it work if you use `schedule` without Telethon? Try getting that to work first, and then add Telethon into the mix.